# I tried installing WampServer but there is an error, How can I handle this?

Tags: php, windows, localhost, wampserver

The image is a screenshot of the error that responded to me when I tried to install the wamp server application
 [image: The image is a screenshot of the error that responded to me when I tried to install the wamp server application]

Comment: Google -> "msvcr110.dll not found" -> https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_8-winapps/the-program-cant-start-because-msvcr110dll-is/f052d325-3af9-4ae5-990b-b080799724db or countless other hits.

Answer (score 0):

One of the first things in the install process is a dialog telling you that you need to make sure you have all the MSVC Runtimes installed BEFORE you install WAMPServer.

To help with this there are a couple of resources on the WAMPSevrer backup repo.

- Go to [The backup repo](http://wampserver.aviatechno.net/?lang=en)
- Go to the bottom of the page.
- Download "All VC Redistribuable Packages (x86) (32bits)" If you are using WAMPSevrer 32bit
- Download "All VC Redistribuable Packages (x86_x64) (32 & 64bits)" If you are using a 64bit WAMPServer

These are zip file and contain multipe MSVC Runtime installs. Run them One at a time, **in a logical version number order** lowest version first.

Once all the runtimes are installed your system will be ready for WAMPServer and ***Any of its ADDON versions of Apache,MySQL,mariaDB and PHP.***

Comment: Thanks! I'll try it out immediately.

Comment: Well, I just tried it out but the Wampserver seems to have another issue. As soon as I open it, it opens and closes in less than a second. I even uninstalled and reinstalled but the issue persists, any idea of how it can be handled?